# Uploads Using Python Google Cloud Storage/Bigquery Client Libraries are Very Slow

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am in a situation where I need to load CSV files that are each hundreds of MB to several GB in size from a third party service into Bigquery. It's not a cloud service so I can't use the transfer service, unfortunately.

Using `google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client load_table_from_file()` or uploading them first to my storage bucket using `google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob upload_from_file()` both result in awfully slow uploads.

I am using python 3.6.9. All metrics are tested using a single file upload. I have tried:

- Running in a docker container on a Google Compute Engine Ubuntu VM.
- Running in a docker container on my mac.
- Running on my mac using just python (no docker).
- Uploading from the whole file in memory, from disk, uncompressed, gzipped.
- Using older and the most recent python client library versions.

**For older (`1.24.0` Bigquery, `1.25.0` Storage) clients I see 1-3MB per second upload speeds. For the `2.13.1` Bigquery client I see 3-4MB per second.**

I have 900+ Mbps up/down on my mac. The Dropbox python client library running on the same setups easily smokes these speeds using the exact same files, and using gsutil on my mac also shows 10x + speeds for the same file.

How can I get usable network speeds using the Google Python Client Libraries?

Comment: The issue should be elsewhere... Any firewall? proxy? stuff like that?

Comment: Nope, no additional network setup. I'd be surprised if it's something like that given the tests I ran (other python modules not experiencing the issue on the same machines/environments, etc.).

Comment: Can you try setting `google.cloud.bigquery.client._DEFAULT_CHUNKSIZE = 100 * 1024 * 1024` in your benchmark script? https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/issues/775